# How to sort the string as ASCII

Tags: r

R sorts character vectors in a sequence not ASCII

For example:

```r
s <- c('a','Any','Aaba','b','B','Baby','Bob')

stringr::str_sort(s, locale = 'en')
[1] 'a' 'Aaba' 'Any' 'b' 'B' 'Baby' 'Bob'
```

How can I sort that in ASCII like this:

```r
'Aaba' 'Any' 'B' 'Baby' 'Bob' 'a' 'b'
```

Comment: I also try `str_sort(s, locale = 'C')`, however it doesn't work. I tried `locale= C, UTF-8, ASCII` and those do not work too.

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
> sort(s, method = "radix")
[1] "Aaba" "Any"  "B"    "Baby" "Bob"  "a"    "b"
```

Comment: Genius~ It worked~ Could u tell me what the parameter `method` does

Comment: @HRronaldo You can type `?sort` see the detailed explanation on it,  which seems a long help manual  although.

Comment: I get it. Thank u~